# Debian | Broken dependencies after update with testing repository

Tags: debian, apt, debian-jessie, dependencies

i'm currently having a dependency problem with a debian jessie resulting from a system upgrade with a testing repository enabled. 
Is there a safe way to go back to my previous configuration?

Not sure why the testing repository was configured actually, as this was made by the previous server admin. The update was also executed by an Ansible script he wrote. When i disable the source, i'm getting a huge list when entering:

> apt-show-versions | grep "No available version in archive"

This is just a part:

```
aspell-de-1901:all 1:2-31 installed: No available version in archive
coinor-libcoinmp1v5:amd64 1.7.6+dfsg1-2 installed: No available version in archive
coinor-libcoinutils3v5:amd64 2.9.15-4 installed: No available version in archive
coinor-libosi1v5:amd64 0.106.9-2+b1 installed: No available version in archive
cpp-6:amd64 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
default-java-plugin:amd64 2:1.8-59 installed: No available version in archive
fonts-droid-fallback:all 1:6.0.1r16-1.1 installed: No available version in archive
fonts-noto-mono:all 20161116-1 installed: No available version in archive
g++-6:amd64 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
galera-3:amd64 25.3.20-1 installed: No available version in archive
gcc-6:amd64 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
gcc-6-base:amd64 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
gcc-7-base:amd64 7.1.0-9 installed: No available version in archive
gcj-6-jre-lib:all 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
gnupg-l10n:all 2.1.18-8 installed: No available version in archive
gnupg2:all 2.1.18-8 installed: No available version in archive
gtk-update-icon-cache:amd64 3.22.16-1 installed: No available version in archive
icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 1.6.2-3.1 installed: No available version in archive
initramfs-tools-core:all 0.130 installed: No available version in archive
laptop-detect:all 0.15 installed: No available version in archive
libapt-inst2.0:amd64 1.5~beta1 installed: No available version in archive
libapt-pkg5.0:amd64 1.5~beta1 installed: No available version in archive
libarchive-cpio-perl:all 0.10-1 installed: No available version in archive
libasan3:amd64 6.4.0-1 installed: No available version in archive
libasprintf0v5:amd64 0.19.8.1-2+b1 installed: No available version in archive
```

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

EDIT:

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
# deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie main

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main

# jessie-updates, previously known as 'volatile'
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

Output of "tail /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*":

```
==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ansible.list <==
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu trusty main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/backports.list <==
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/bloonix.list <==
deb https://download.bloonix.de/repos/debian/ jessie main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotdeb.list <==
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/draios.list <==
#deb http://download.draios.com/stable/deb stable-$(ARCH)/

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elasticsearch-2.x.list <==
deb http://packages.elastic.co/elasticsearch/2.x/debian stable main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/git-lfs.list <==
deb https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/debian/ jessie main

==> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/testing.list <==
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing main non-free contrib
```

Comment: Please edit the content of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*` files into the question.

Comment: You should clean up the sources. They should all point to repositories with the version corresponding to your own. And mixing ubuntu and debian repositories is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, that is true, the one ubuntu source is the ansible source and is taken from the official ansible documentation here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-releases-via-apt-debian. This shouldn't be the source of the problem